# JavaScript code snippet Tidy function injects a separating space into the null coalesce operator

Tags: bug, code-formatting, stack-snippets

For JavaScript snippets, the Tidy feature injects a space between the question marks that compose the nullish coalescing operator `??`<sup>[1]</sup>.

Example:

Prior to Tidy:

```
console.log(((a, b) => {
  return a ?? b;
})(null, 'b'));
```

The snippet below with Tidy applied injects a space into the operator which produces a syntax error when run.

```js
console.log(((a, b) => {
  return a ? ? b;
})(null, 'b'));
```

<sup>1</sup>[Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Related: [Snippet `Tidy` for Javascript probably incorrect for dynamic `import()`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401901/4642212) and [Snippet Tidy breaks Optional Chaining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348290/289905). This is already [fixed upstream in JS-Beautify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401909/4642212).